# Access class variables with __repr__()

Tags: python, class, repr

I'm relatively new to Python, and I was wondering how you can "configure" a class the way that it returns a tuple if you print it.

Example: I have a class with the attributes a, b & c:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4
        self.c = 5
```

Now how do I "configure" the class the way I can access these attributes the following way:

```
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> print bar
<foo(3, 4, 5)>
>>> print bar[1]
4
```

I know `__repr__()` and `__str__()`, but if I try to access the numbers via the "[]", there is the following error:

```
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I know that it is possible somehow, as example the `pygame` library has an object called `Rect` which works exactly the way above.

Thanks!

Comment: put `__slots__` in your class or inherit it from list/tuple

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko: Giving your class `__slots__` has no effect on this, and inheriting from list or tuple has other, often undesirable effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `AttributeError` says, you need to define a `__getitem__` method for your class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4
        self.c = 5

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self.a
        elif index == 1:
            return self.b
        elif index == 2:
            return self.c
        else:
            raise KeyError("Index must be 0, 1 or 2")
```

Ugly, but works:

```
>>>bar = Foo()
>>>print bar
<__main__.Foo instance at xxxxxxxxxxxx>
>>>print bar[1]
4
```

If you don't need `a`, `b` and `c` to be separate variables, you can use:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = [3, 4, 5]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.elements[index]
```

Although in this case, I would consider using a `list` directly...

Comment: Ugly? What would you suggest then?

Comment: What edits? Did you mean the elif-row when you said "ugly"?
Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Yes, precisely the `elif` block. I repeat, consider using a list if you do not need three separed variables (second snippet). You are welcome :)

Comment: How about `return [self.a, self.b, self.c][index]`?

Comment: Yeah @SvenMarnach, that's nice, although it will rebuild the list for every call to `__getitem__`. If the indexing is used frequently, there might be performance issues.

Comment: Ok, I don't use it only to store data, I also have some methods...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two totally separate questions here.  If you set a value as `self.a`, you need to access it as `self.a`, not using `[]`.  Just have your `__str__` do something like:

```
return '<foo({0}, {1}, {2})>'.format(self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

If you want to be able to access those variables using `[]`, then you need to define `__getitem__` as described by Stefano Sanfilippo's answer and in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want. Setting the values as self.a would be accessed with `print bar.a`. However, slight workaround, when you set all the self values, a dictionary is formed. You can get an array by pulling the values from all the self attributes.

```
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> print bar
<foo(3, 4, 5)>
>>> bar.__dict__
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}
>>> bar.__dict__.values()
[3,4,5]
```